# How combine two list in list into one list?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have:

```
A = [[a,b,c,d],[1,2,3,4]]
B = [[1.2,1.7],[1.6,1.8]]
```

I want to combine 2 list to one list

```
C = [[a,b,c,d,1.2,1.7],[1,2,3,4,1.6,1.8]]
```

How can I do that in Python?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Have you tried anything, written a piece of code?

Comment: `C = [A[0] + B[0], A[1] + B[1]]`.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of flattening a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot's of different ways of combining two lists.

You can add two lists together:

```
[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]
```

Will give you:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

You can append a list to a list of lists:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].append([7,8,9])
```

Will give you:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

You can zip two lists as well:

```
zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

Will give you:

```
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

What it looks like you're looking for is:

```
C = []

for sublist_1, sublist_2 in zip(A, B):
    C.append(sublist_1 + sublist_2)
```

Or more compactly using list comprehension:

```
C = [sublist_1 + sublist_2 for sublist_2, sublist_2 in zip(A,B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `extend()` method to concatenate the elements of one list to another and then append this resulting list to the final list.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i].extend(b[i])
    c.append(a[i])
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and  [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) for this

```
In [110]: A
Out[110]: [[2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

In [111]: B
Out[111]: [[1.2, 1.7], [1.6, 1.8]]

In [112]: import itertools

In [113]: list(itertools.starmap(lambda x,y:x+y,zip(A,B)))
Out[113]: [[2, 4, 5, 6, 1.2, 1.7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1.6, 1.8]]
```